# Recharts dataMax with React Table returning first value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graph, react-table, recharts

I'm building a simple React app pulling data from an API, using React Table to organize the data, and connecting Recharts to graph.

I am trying to graph two fields- "UnitPrice" and "District".  Not all objects in the JSON contain "UnitPrice".  When I set the axis domain to `domain={[0, 'dataMax']}` the graph always returns the first non-zero value as the `dataMax`.

I've tried to write some functions like below to replace `dataMax` but no luck.

```
const MaxY = ({ UnitPrice, i }) => {
  let max;
  for (i = 0; i < UnitPrice.length; i++) {
    if (UnitPrice[i] > max) {
      max = UnitPrice[i];
    }
  }
  return max;
};
```

I've also tried to remove the items which don't contain `UnitPrice` or duplicate `District` values but failed.  Will I need to remap the data separate from React Table for this to be able to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be Recharts default behavior if `NaN` is supplied to the second element of the `domain` prop, or it is the result of Recharts internally calculating `dataMax`.

This can often happen if the JSON encodes `UnitPrice` as a string. If that's the case, parse it to an integer.

While I can't say for sure, considering that Recharts doesn't seem to handle string to integer conversion, you'll likely wan't to remove any elements which don't have a `UnitPrice` - or provide a default number value. If you don't, Recharts may calculate a `NaN` as the maximum Y value, which will result in it's fallback behavior.

Comment: If memory serves, `UnitPrice` was being passed as a string as you said. I seem to recall some type conversion built into Recharts that wasn't working but it was a while ago.  Thanks Alex.